# How a JMS based Weblogic server can cosume a message created via MSMQ?

Tags: jms, weblogic, msmq

I am new to this JMS, MSMQ, Weblogic things and don't have much idea about them. Can someone please guide me regarding my above question - How a JMS based Weblogic server can cosume a message created via MSMQ? Any reading material, links will be helpful, working examples would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the MSMQ product group's blog:

[JMS and MSMQ interoperability](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/motleyqueue/archive/2009/06/08/jms-and-msmq-interoperability.aspx)